# mySQL WHERE clause with column = val1 OR coumn IN values

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to query through my db to receive all posts which contain a certain user_id as owner or participant of the post.

My DB structure is as following:

```
id: INT
media_id: INT
owner_id: INT
participants: STRING eg. [1,2]
comments: TEXT eg. [{},{}]
```

Here are two example entries:

```
id: 1, media_id: 2, owner_id: 1, participants: "[1,2]", comments: "[]"
id: 2, media_id: 3, owner_id: 2, participants: "[2,1]", comments: "[]"
```

What I am trying to achieve is to get all rows where the user with the id `1` is part of the column `owner_id` OR `participants`

My current query looks as following:

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE owner_id = 1 OR participants IN "1"
```

And the result which I receive is only the line where `1` is the `owner_id`

I might understand the IN equasion wrong but `1` is a part of participants in both rows, therefore I should get both rows as result, shouldn't I?

Comment: You should consider refactoring the db schema and introduce many-to-many relationship instead of the string representation of participants if you are planing your application to grow. Doing full-text search in string is not fast operation since you can not leverage indexes.

Comment: another option is to change participants column structure to a comma separated ids without `[]` and use `FIND_IN_SET(1, participants)` in your condition

Comment: Oh my... I didn't know I could do 1,2,3,4... directly in the database. I sticked with the STRING format because it also represented the structure I'm working with in my javascript application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are willing to change your data structure for `participants` field to a comma separated value e.g. `1,2` or `2,1`, you can then use:

`SELECT * FROM posts WHERE owner_id = 1 OR FIND_IN_SET(1, participants);`

Comment: Oh my... I didn't know I could actually do that - I never had to ^^. I came up with this weird string in DB solution because It's the structure I use in my webapplication in my javascript code

Comment: In your web application, if you intend to use participants field as an array you can convert `1,2` string to an array using `split` method, e.g. `participants.split(',')`

Comment: Thank you. I'll give it a shot as soon as I'm home.

Comment: What type should I set my column ? since its not a varchar anymore

Comment: Yea, sorry I wasnt able to try it out earlier. This method works.

Answer (score 2):

**This will do the trick:**

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE owner_id = 1 
OR participants like "%,1]" 
OR participants like "[1,%" 
OR participants like "%,1,%"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the KeyWord Like... the syntax example:

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE owner_id = 1 OR participants Like '%1%'
```

For other case you can use this:

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE owner_id = 1 
OR participants like "%,1" 
OR participants like "1,%" 
OR participants like "%,1,%"
```

Comment: I Edit my post with generics numbers

Answer (score 0):

You should change query to :

```
SELECT * FROM posts 
WHERE (owner_id = 1 OR participants like "%,1" OR participants like "1,%" OR participants like "%,1,%")
```

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed not the correct approach of the `IN` clause. It should look like:

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE owner_id = 1 OR participants IN (1)
```

And its only need if looking for multiple values (in this case id's) like:

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE owner_id = 1 OR participants IN (1,5,15)
```

But because your `participants` column is a string it is not going to work, because MySQL is not parse/do something with the string to make it usable in the way you tried.

There is a possible and ugly way to achief what you want and do not change your database structure, but I do recommend to change it to a more usable approach with a relation table for a many-to-many relationship?

But the ugly way to achief it:

```
SELECT * FROM posts 
WHERE owner_id = 1 
OR (participants LIKE '[1,%' OR participants LIKE '%,1,%' OR participants LIKE '%,1]')
```

#### Better approach

A nice way good be to change your `posts` table slightly:

```
[posts]
id INT
media_id INT
owner_id INT
comments: TEXT eg. [{},{}]
```

And add a relational table what could like:

```
[post_participant]
post_id: INT
user_id: INT // -> or named participant_id
```

In this way you can get the proper posts with a query like:

```
SELECT p.* FROM posts p
LEFT JOIN post_participant pp ON pp.post_id = p.id AND pp.user_id = p.owner_id
WHERE p.owner_id = 1 
OR pp.user_id IS NOT NULL
```